# Show that Affine Curves are not compact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Hi guys I have a question and not sure how to connect the dots. I am suppose to show that over a algebraically closed field $K=\mathbb{C}$. The affine variety in $K \times K$ is never compact. There is a hint" show that for the defining non-constant polynomial $f(x,y)\in K[x,y]$ for all but finitely many values of $a \in K$ there is a $b\in C$ such that $f(a,b)=0$.

So what I am thinking is that by the fundamental theorem of algebra we can factor $f(x,y)= \prod_{i=1} ^d (\alpha_i x + \beta_i y)$. Ie just factor it to linear factors then clearly for a fixed a;
$\alpha a +\beta y=0$
thus solve for y and get $y=\frac{- \alpha}{\beta}a$ so if we let $b=\frac{- \alpha}{\beta}a$ and this will make the polynomial zero. What I do not see is how this applies to the argument. Are we using something like we know the field is compact and the only compact subsets have to be closed?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true for every affine subvariety since a point of $C^2$ is a compact subset. But it is true if the affine subvariety is defined by a function $f$.

A compact subset of $C^2$ is bounded. Suppose that the affine variety $V$  defined by $f\in K[x,y]$ is compact, there exists $M$ such that for every $x\in V$, $\|x\|<M/2$. But $f(M,y)$ has a solution $b$, so $(M,b)\in V$ and $\|(M,b)\|=\sqrt{M^2+\mid b\mid}>M/2$. Contradiction.